# How to create a new column in Pandas DataFrame based on a combination 1 and many columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
   Cond  Column_A  Column_B  Column_C  Cumulative_Count
0     1     -0.60     -0.12     -0.17                 1
1     0      0.30      0.70      0.98                 0
2     1     -0.45     -0.71     -0.99                 2
3     1      0.60      0.12      0.17                 1
4     0      0.20      0.80      0.60                 0
5     1      0.70      0.14      0.20                 1
```

I would like to create a column Cumulative_Count that counts occurrence of an event based on multiple conditions such as:

1) If Cond=1 and (Column_A<0.5 or Column B>0.5) then Cumulative_Count=Cumulative_Count+1

2) If Cond=1 and (Column_B<0.5 or Column B>0.5) then Cumulative_Count=Cumulative_Count+1

3) If Cond=1 and (Column_C<0.5 or Column C>0.5) then Cumulative_Count=Cumulative_Count+1

I would like to use NumPy arrays to perform it because my dataset is very large.  I tried using below code, it is not throwing error, but the result is not correct. And, I need to use it for all columns if possible because I have 50+ columns.

```
df['Cum_Count']=0
df['Cum_Count']=np.where((df['Cond']>0 & ((df['Column_A']<-0.5) | (df['Column_A']>0.5))), df['Cum_Count']+1, df['Cum_Count'])
```

Comment: Thank you and just to clarify, even though I have about 50 columns, in the end I need only one column Cum_Count that would loop through multiple columns and  record the number of times a condition was met across the columns (for this example, I included 3 columns).

Comment: I noticed a small typo, in the description of conditions, it should be < - 0.5 instead of <0.5

Comment: regarding the question about Column B, the answer is no it is not a typo.  I am trying to capture relatively high deviations and anything less that - 0.5 or higher that 0.5 can be considered as a deviation to capture if Cond =1.  And, I want to count how many times it happens across 50 columns of data to determine rows that have the highest number of deviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing with

```
cond1=df.filter(like='Column')
cond2=df.Cond

df['count']=(cond1.gt(0.5)|cond1.lt(-0.5)).__and__(cond2,axis=0).sum(1)
```

Comment: Thank you and this is very helpful.  Two questions: 1) is there a way to apply cond1 to multiple columns? 2) Would you recommend a link to learn the method in a bit more details?

Comment: @Nora you can check with np.select . Also you can check with pandas doc , all those method there is some example list below it .